# How to post int/integer value as json from dart/flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

I am using asp.net core web API as back-end. There is a method that accepts a single integer value.

```
Method([FromBody] int value)
```

I want to post the integer value from dart/flutter.
I tried the following with the dart `http` package.

```
Http.post(url, body:0,headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}

Http.post(url, body:{0},headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}

Http.post(url, body:convert.jsonEncode(0),headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}

Http.post(url, body:convert.jsonEncode({0}),headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}
```

All my above tries failed with error
"Invalid argument: invalid request body "0""

Comment: @dhaval-solanki  Thanks for formatting text. I posted the question from mobile.

Comment: Okay, no problem we are here to help and guide to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer my code

1. import

   ```
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   ```
2. http request

   ```
   var client = new http.Client();
   client.post(Uri.encodeFull("Your url"), body: {
     "param1": "value1",
     "param2": 11, // integer value type       
   }).then((response) {
     client.close();
     if (this.mounted && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //enter your code for change state
     }
   }).catchError((onError) {
      client.close();
      print("Error: $onError");
   });
   ```

I hope it  will help you.

PS:

```
var client = new http.Client();
var response = await client.post(Uri.encodeFull("Your Url"), body : "0", header : {/*Your headers*/"});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I have to only send the integer value, not with parameter names.  Like only 0 in body. It is working when I post using PostMan

Comment: Can you share your Postman request? Or try this. => body:{"" : 1}

Comment: yes, i tried that ("":1) but not working.  In Postman request I just pass the 0 with json type selected and that works fine.

Comment: Please share your postman screen. Not need URL. Only need headers and body screen.

Comment: headers = https://i.postimg.cc/BnsT008m/Screenshot-from-2019-10-02-16-44-39.png    and      body = https://i.postimg.cc/CxNjMQkS/Screenshot-from-2019-10-02-16-45-17.png

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to send an HTTP request to an API that has an integer as one of its arguments(age). Dart wanted me to convert the int into a string and the API was not accepting the int as a string. Hence I was getting the same error and ended up in this question.

My solution was to store the input in a map, add a header {"content-type":"application/json"} and pass the map in the body arguement.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


Future<String> register_user() async {
  var req_body = new Map();

  req_body['username'] = 'John Doe';
  req_body['age'] = 20; /* The integer */

  final response = await http.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8081/user/register',
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
         body: jsonEncode(req_body));


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var object = json.decode(response.body);

    return object.toString();
  } else if (response.statusCode == 422) {
    return 'Error';
  } else {
    return 'Can not connect to server';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
Http.post(url, body:{"id": "0"},headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I have to only send the integer value, not with parameter names. Like only 0 in body. It is working when I post using PostMan

Answer (score 0):

Can you try bellow one

```
var queryParameters = {
                'value': '0'
        };
        var uri =
                Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/api/sub_api_part/', queryParameters); //replace between  part and your url
        var response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
                    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Please note that I am doing POST not GET and also  I have to only send the integer value, not with parameter names. Like only 0 in body. It is working when I post using PostMan