# How to send boolean value or int value in a http request body?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

How to send a boolean value or an integer in http request body in dart? The documentation says that I can only send string, list or a Map. How to make it work for boolean or integer in Dart?

Comment: use Dio plugin its a powerful http client for flutter

Comment: Without the help of the plugin, is there no other option?

Comment: Check this url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183559/how-to-post-int-integer-value-as-json-from-dart-flutter/58183645#58183645

Comment: You need to start accepting the answers to some of your questions. (Otherwise, you'll find that people stop answering them...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you saw in the documentation, you can only send those three things: a byte array, a string or a map of string to string. In fact, in the end, you are just sending a byte array. The other options get converted to bytes before sending.

A string is converted to bytes by transforming it into bytes using utf-8 (or some other encoding specified by the content-type header).

A map of string to string is encoded to first as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and then to bytes. That encoding can, of course, only encode strings.

So the answer to your question really depends on where/how the server expects to receive the fields. If it's expecting them in a form, then it's your responsibility to convert, say, a boolean into whatever string the server expects. Maybe that's 'true'/'false' or '1'/'0' or something else. Make your map like this:

```
int someInt;
bool someBool;
var formData = <String, String>{
  'an_int_value' : someInt.toString(),
  'a_bool_value' : someBool.toString(), // assuming 'true'/'false' is OK
};
```

Also consider the possibility that your server requires a completely different encoding, like JSON. Then you would convert your map to JSON, then pass that as a string, setting the content-type appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

**Try this approach which I use in my projects**

```
  void apiPost(){

    var body = jsonEncode(
        {
          "string":"test",
          "bool":true,
          "int":1
        });

    http.post("url here",body: body,headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}).then((response) {
      Map map = json.decode(response.body);
    });
  }
```